# How to populate variable in pl sql on declaration in store procedure with sql statement return

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

So I have a variable on the declaration on the store procedure. It must have a default value that is populated on the return of a sql statement. The thing is that that variable is used in the declaration of the query of a cursor, thats why it needs to be populated on the declaration. How am i supposed to do this?

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROCESAR  AS

ultimaejecucion date := select fecha from table where rownum<=1;

--I know I have to use the word INTO but throws me error when i compile. 

cursor cursor_licencias is
select  lic.campo1
from  lic lic
where lic.licfhing >= ultimaejecucion


BEGIN
open cursor
.
.
.

END PROCESAR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is quite unclear. If your cursor always depends on values from another table, you should include this table to query, as Multisync advised. If your cursor also has to depend on different rows of that table, you can use cursor parameters to choose that row:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROCESAR  AS

cursor cursor_licencias (cursor_parameter number default 1234) is
  select  lic.campo1
  from  lic lic
  where lic.licfhing >= (select fecha from table where column = cursor_parameter);

BEGIN
  open cursor cursor_licencias;  -- using with default value

  open cursor cursor_licencias (5678);  -- using with value '5678'

END PROCESAR;
```

[Example in oracle documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#BABHCIAC)

Comment: Ok, thats exactly what i wanted! I didnt know cursors can have parameters. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You may move it into the cursor declaration:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROCESAR  AS

cursor cursor_licencias is
select  lic.campo1
from  lic lic
where lic.licfhing >= (select fecha from table where rownum<=1);


BEGIN
open cursor
.
.
.

END PROCESAR;
```

if you need this field somewhere else you can assign the value to the **ultimaejecucion** right after BEGIN

Comment: I have thought that but the thing is ultimaejecucion is used many times in the query of the cursor. I put it one time just for simplicity. And if i use that method it would be too complicated and long the query of the crusor

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
declare

  l_date date;

  -- the value of l_date does not matter at this point
  cursor sel_cur is
  select 'It works' as val
  from dual
  where sysdate > l_date;

begin
    -- populate l_date using query
    select sysdate - 1
    into l_date
    from dual;

    -- open cursor (implicitly).  
    -- here the value of l_date is used in the execution of the query
    for rec in sel_cur
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(rec.val);
    end loop;


end;
```

Comment: It seems it does not work. Could you please post the code that corresponds with the one i put_

Comment: not sure why you think it does not work (set serveroutput on first, and you'll see the output: It works ).  I'm showing the approach here, not rewriting your exact procedure.  Hope it helps

Comment: But you are declaring the cursor with a variable that has not been populated yet. And then populate the variable. That is what it does not make sense. Maybe i am confused and the declaration is just the declaration and when the open executes is when the query of the cursor is run. Anyways i used parameters and worked! Thank you!

Comment: The variable (l_date) is not evaluated when you declare the cursor.  It is evaluated when you open the cursor.  So the declaration of the cursor simply sees that you are comparing a date to a date, Oracle isn't plugging in any values in the declaration.